# PHP: Help replacing date text

Tags: php, date, str-replace

I'm working with a CMS spanish website, and I'm trying to replace the months to spanish.

This is how it looks like with the date function **date("F j, Y, g:i a")**:

```
August 24, 2011, 1:47 pm
```

Now I want it to look like this:

```
Agosto 24, 2011, 1:47 pm
```

With str_replace function the string gets replaced, but the day and hour are missing.

```
Agosto
```

This is the code I'm using to define it:

```
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Belize");
    $p['time'] = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $time = $p['time'];
    $search  = array('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    $subject ='August';
    $replace = array('Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
    $time = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);

    $echo = $time;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) to specify the correct language before calling `date`. E.g.

```
/* Set locale to Spanish */
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
```

P.S. In your original code, using that approach, you need to replace:

```
$time = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

with

```
$time = str_replace($search, $replace, $time);
```

But I would recommend using `setlocale` so you don't have to worry about doing this yourself. Also,

```
$echo = $time;
```

is totally wrong; it should be:

```
echo $time;
```

Comment: It does not work for me for some reason, the date always remains in english.

Comment: Hmmm... it's *possible* you don't have the Spanish locale available. If you're on a UNIX box, try checking /usr/share/locale/ - anything relating to 'es' there?

Comment: OK, as gAMBOOKa pointed out, you need to use strftime() to take advantage of the locale.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel

Use [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Answer (score 1):

`$echo = $time;` ?!
Shouldn't it be  `echo $time;` ?

your code should be something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Belize");
$time = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$search  = array('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
$replace = array('Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
$time = str_replace($search, $replace, $time);
echo $time;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the $subject of your str_replace should be $time, otherwise you're doing a search and replace on the string 'August'